# How can I implement sorting in my crud table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

Here is my backend code

```
app.get("/sortedcustomers", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM customer_info ORDER BY contacted", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});
```

which gives me data in this form:
[{"ID":1,"name":"Queen","email":"Queen@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":13,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":3,"name":"Alex","email":"Alex@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":7,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-04-30T09:50:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":2,"name":"Wayne","email":"Wayne@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":10,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-04-30T09:50:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":4,"name":"Jack","email":"Jack@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":3,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-04-30T09:50:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"}]

Then my frontend code:

```
function Home(props) {
  const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const getSortedCustomerList = () => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/sortedcustomers").then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  };
  const updateCustomerContacted = (ID) => {
    Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update", {
      contacted: newContacted,
      ID: ID,
    }).then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(
        customerList.map((val) => {
          return val.ID == ID
            ? {
                ID: val.ID,
                name: val.name,
                email: val.email,
                counts_of_visit: val.counts_of_visit,
                latest_time_of_visit: formatDatetime(val.latest_time_of_visit),
                contacted: newContacted,
              }
            : val;
        })
      );
    });
  };

  //function to format the datetime to correct format
  const formatDatetime = (datetime) => {
    const dateStr = new Date(datetime).toLocaleDateString("en-CA");
    const timeStr = new Date(datetime).toLocaleTimeString();
    return `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
  };

  const deleteCustomer = (ID) => {
    Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/stats/delete/${ID}`).then(
      (response) => {
        setCustomerList(
          customerList.filter((val) => {
            return val.ID != ID;
          })
        );
      }
    );
  };

  //pagination
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
  const customersPerPage = 5; //change this number according to desired number of rows in a page
  const pagesVisited = pageNumber * customersPerPage;
  const displayCustomers = customerList
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + customersPerPage)
    .map((val, key) => {
      const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
        "en-CA"
      );
      const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
      const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
      const my_serial = key + pageNumber * customersPerPage;
      return (
        <tr>
          {/*}
          <td>{val.ID}</td>
      */}
          <td>{my_serial + 1}</td>
          <td>{val.name}</td>
          <td>{val.email}</td>
          <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
          <td>{dateTime}</td>
          <td>{val.contacted}</td>
          <td>
            <select
              onChange={(event) => {
                setNewContacted(event.target.value);
              }}
            >
              <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
                Select Yes/No
              </option>
              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={() => {
                updateCustomerContacted(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger"
              onClick={() => {
                deleteCustomer(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  //to account for the fact that total number of customers cannot be divided equally among the pages
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(customerList.length / customersPerPage);
  //page change
  const changePage = ({ selected }) => {
    setPageNumber(selected);
  };

  //update contacted column
  const [newContacted, setNewContacted] = useState(0);

  //export to csv function

  const DataSet = [
    {
      columns: [
        {
          title: "S/N",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 125 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Customer Information",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Customer Email",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Counts of Visit",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 175 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Latest Time of Visit",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Contacted?",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
      ],
      data: customerList.map((val, key) => [
        { value: key + 1, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.name, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.email, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.counts_of_visit, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        {
          value: formatDatetime(val.latest_time_of_visit),
          style: { font: { sz: "14" } },
        },
        { value: val.contacted, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
      ]),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="warning">
              <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Customer Information</h4>
              <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}></p>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <div className="dashboardcontainer">
                <div className="container"></div>
                <table className="customertable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      {/*}
                      <th>S/N</th>
              */}
                      <th>S/N</th>
                      <th>Customer Name</th>
                      <th>Customer Email</th>
                      <th>Counts of Visit</th>
                      <th>Latest Time of Visit</th>
                      <th onClick={getSortedCustomerList}>Contacted?</th>
                      <th>Edit Contacted</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>{displayCustomers}</tbody>
                </table>
                <ReactPaginate
                  previousLabel={"Previous"}
                  nextLabel={"Next"}
                  pageCount={pageCount}
                  onPageChange={changePage}
                  containerClassName={"paginationBttns"}
                  pageLinkClassName={"paginationNumber"}
                  previousLinkClassName={"previousBttn"}
                  nextLinkClassName={"nextBttn"}
                  disabledClassName={"paginationDisabled"}
                  activeClassName={"paginationActive"}
                />
                <ExcelFile
                  filename="Customer Information"
                  element={
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-success float-right m-3"
                    >
                      Export to Excel
                    </button>
                  }
                >
                  <ExcelSheet
                    dataSet={DataSet}
                    name="Customer Information Report"
                  ></ExcelSheet>
                </ExcelFile>
              </div>
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But the thing about my frontend is that when I click on the "Contacted?" header column it does show the sorted data, but how do I make it show the reverse sorted list then the normal unsorted customer list on the last click. So first click sorted list works, but second click sorted reverse list doesn't work and 3rd click unsorted list doesn't work.

So, basically, I have this crud table, when I click contacted column, it sorts itself accordingly, but when I click again it does not sort in reverse order, then when I click again it does not go back to unsorted order, how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
customerList.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b - a;
})
```

,or, if that doesn't work:

```
customerList.reverse()
```

Comment: both doesn't work

Comment: I added
```
  const displaySortedCustomers = () => {
    customerList.sort(function (a, b) {
      return b - a;
    });
  };
```

Then added a onClick method on the column header to run this function but it does not sort.